# why android:id isn't added to the R.java in menu resource file?

Tags: android

Now, I am studying the android developer training. In 'Adding Action Buttons' I got some problems.
I wrote the xml code like below, but in `MainActivity.java`, `action_search` and `action_settings` got error and compiler said it cannot be resolved or not a field. And then, I read the recommendation to fix the code that "create field `action_search` in type `id`". I've already wrote the code `"@+id/action_search"` and `"@+id/action_settings"`. Why this error appeared please let me know!

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
   <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

EDIT: Code as requested

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Did you do Project --> Clean after updating ? What's the error now ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work.

Comment: post your code and logcat pls...

Comment: public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // Handle presses on the action bar items
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.action_search:
             openSearch();
             return true;
         case R.id.action_settings:
             openSettings();
             return true;
         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
 }

////////////////please copy and paste to the notepad

Comment: Are you importing android.R or your project's .R?

Comment: use different title name like **android:title="Action"** in action_search.

Comment: Nathan Walters-> What do I have to do if I wanna know that?

Comment: look at your java file on top and see whether you've 'import android.R' listed there. If so, delete that and then you do Project --> Clean after updating ? Look for the error message now ?

Comment: Gem_Ram- > There isn't "import android.R".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error check this link.

Comment: I solved this problem by added this code <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> All of you are so kind. Thank you!

Comment: Noin - I was just typing that to have what you noticed in your code...u realized urself...cool...welcome to learning :)